# Select first value from list using expression builder - Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, expressionbuilder

I'm currently trying to set the default value of a combobox to the first value in that combobox using the expression builder. The box is populated by a table with one column. I'm quite new to Access, so sorry in advance if this is a silly question.  Here's my code so far that doesn't work.

```
=[cboProduct].[ListIndex](0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Austin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is:

```
=[cboProduct].ItemData(0)
```

or to be strict:

```
=[cboProduct].ItemData(Abs([cboProduct].ColumnHeads))
```